# Estimation of rare earth elements in the SUAC complex

Tags: geology, geochemistry, mineralogy, petrology, rare-earth

I am currently competing in a case study competition a part of which has asked us to estimate the amount of Nd, Pr, and Dy in the SUAC complex ([Sung Valley Ultramafic-Alkaline-Carbonatite](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/264791627_REE_mineralization_in_the_carbonatites_of_the_Sung_Valley_Ultramafic-Alkaline-Carbonatite_Complex_Meghalaya_India)) in electric vehicle or wind turbine equivalents.

I recently read a report on the surface exploration of the carbonatite bodies in the area and while they've given the width, length and concentration of these elements within the carbonatite bodies but they haven't given the depth.

I was wondering as to how I would calculate the amount of those REEs with the given data. Any help would be appreciated.

*The part of the case study mentioned for your reference:*

**Using publicly available data on the amount of REE contained within the Sung
Hill carbonatite, and estimates on the amount of specific elements required for
various magnets used in electric vehicle motors and wind power turbines,
estimate an “electric vehicle equivalent” and a “wind power turbine equivalent”
if the currently known REE resource at Sung Hill would be extracted to
completion.**

Comment: Outside my expertise. I did a quick search on Google Scholar. The deposits in the Sung Valley appear to be quite shallow: Yamuna Singh, "Strategic and Critical Element Potential of Indian Carbonatites." *Journal of Geosciences Research*, Vol. 5, No. 2, July 2020, pp. 161-170: "About 1300 tonnes of Nb₂O₅, contained in 6.75 million tonnes of ore (av. grade 0.02% Nb₂O₅), present over 5 km² area, has been estimated in residual soil"

Comment: @njuffa thank you for sharing this.